# divide rsa private key in two halves

Tags: java, key, rsa

i would like to divide the rsa private key into two halves and store them in two different places, how can I do it?

```
public GenerateKeys(int keylength) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    keylength=512;
    this.keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    this.keyGen.initialize(keylength, random);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with split? Are you referring to a RSA-CRT key or do you just want to get the mathematical values like modulus and exponent? Please edit your question add these details.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135904/split-rsa-private-key-into-two-parts-securely

Comment: @Robert i just want to divide it, i m not referring to  a RSA-CRT thank you

Comment: Splitting an RSA key into multiple parts is nonsense. In case you want to distribute each key part to a different person you may consider using a real secret sharing algorithm instead such as [Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing).

Comment: @Robert: Overstated. Two-person control schemes have historically used the splitting method that choppe shows below. It's simple and it's secure under reasonable assumptions. Shamir's scheme does have real advantages for some scenarios, especially for more complicated splitting scenarios (eg, a 2 out of 3 scheme). And of course, it is a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example, which will split your private key in to two parts, D1 and D2. Similar to the discussion presented [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135904/split-rsa-private-key-into-two-parts-securely)

```
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class OnetimePad{

    public static byte[] xor(byte[] key, byte[] rand){
        if(key.length != rand.length){
            return null;
        }
        byte[] ret = new byte[key.length];
        for(int i =0; i < key.length; i++){
            ret[i] = (byte)((key[i] ^ rand[i]) );
        }

        return ret;
    }

     public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();  


        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair keypair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();  
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();

        //Private Key Part 1
        byte[] D1 = new byte[privateKeyBytes.length];
        random.nextBytes(D1);

        //Private Key Part 2
        byte[] D2 = xor(privateKeyBytes, D1);

        //now D1 and D2 are split parts of private keys..

        //Let's verify if we could reproduce them back 
        byte[] privateKeyByesTmp = xor(D2, D1);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyByesTmp);
        PrivateKey privateKey2 = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        boolean same = privateKey.equals(privateKey2); 
        if(same){
            System.out.println("Key loaded successfully");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Ooops");
        }

     }
}
```

**Note:**
Please check following documentation of SecureRandom on [random seed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html). Specially the section highlighted

> Many SecureRandom implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed. Other implementations may produce true random numbers, and yet others may use a combination of both techniques.

Comment: This needs to use SecureRandom if you want the split to be secure. In fact, as it stands now, the full private key could be very easily recovered from the D2 split.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk, Thank you, Yes, you are right; Hence I have commented // Use a good non-deterministic random number generator in the comments; It is up to the poster to chose a good random number generator

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk, SecureRandom alone would not make the split secure; Hence the statement non-deterministic true random number generator is the emphasis here.